# Matching Second OR Middle Word Assistance

Tags: regex

I need to match the beginning, and end for multiple lines.  The idea is to have the end optional, not sure how to do that.  Example are

```
bs-messages-child (match messages)
bs-inbox (match inbox)
bs-followers-child (match followers)
```

The best I can do is `'bs-(.*)-?(.*)'` - which still leaves the -child on the longer strings.  Is it possible to match this pattern w regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated class:

```
bs-([^-\s]+)(?:-([^-\s]+))?
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/fR4iH8)

`[^-\s]+` will match non-dash characters and non-space characters.

Comment: @GregL Hmm, no, there shouldn't be any issue as far as I know... How are you using `preg_match`?

Comment: `preg_match( '/^bs-(.*?)(?:-child)?$/', implode( ' ', $menu_item->classes), $matches );`  - the preg_match is checking inside an array, so I am using implode. I cannot change the array, or handle it in a different way.

Comment: @GregL What do you see when you echo the result of the implode? Because using the regex on plain strings [seems to work](http://ideone.com/eRkcK8).

Comment: @GregL Awesome that you managed to solve your problem then! :)

Comment: Not without your help Jerry!  Thank you again man!  Last question I promise!  I will be working with regex a lot, can you reference me a good place to learn it better?

Comment: @GregL No problem! Many users reference [this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/), which I find great as well.

Answer (score 1):

You could do with below:

```
^bs-(.*?)(?:-child)?$
```